# Python List values getting changed/mutated

Tags: python

I've got this simple code here running for project Euler question 31.

The Euler Q is not required; I just want to know, why my list values are getting mutated, i.e. this is printing a list of many lists of [2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0].

```
coins = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]


perms = []
def check(c):
    if sum(c) == 2:
        print c, "lol", sum(c)
        perms.append(c)
    return perms

c = [0] * 5
for c[0] in coins:
    for c[1] in coins:
        for c[2] in coins:
            for c[3] in coins:
                for c[4] in coins:
                    check(c)

print perms
```

This doesn't work for some reason and the output is

```
[[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]...]

perms = []
for c1 in coins:
    for c2 in coins:
        for c3 in coins:
            for c4 in coins:
                for c5 in coins:
                    if c1+c2+c3+c4+c5 == 2:
                        print c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
                        perms.append([c1,c2,c3,c4,c5])


print perms
```

However, this one works, and the output is

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0], [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0, 0.5], [0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0],[0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 0.2], [0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2, 0.5], [0.1, 0.2, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2],[0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0], [0.1, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0, 0.2]...]
```

What is the difference between the two?

And also, how can I shorten my code, maybe a recursive function?
So that instead of doing c1 in coins, c2 in coins and so on, I just have one or two loops to do the same job.

Comment: *"maybe a recursive function?"* Yep, that would be better here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `c` still gets modified *after* it has been added to `perms`. You can instead pass a copy to `check`, then it seems to work.

```
c = [0] * 5
for c[0] in coins:
    for c[1] in coins:
        for c[2] in coins:
            for c[3] in coins:
                for c[4] in coins:
                    check(c[:]) # c[:] creates a copy of c
```

BTW, I didn't even know `for c[1] in coins` is valid Python syntax...

Also, you might want to have a look at `itertools`, particularly [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

---

A recursive function could look roughly like this:

```
def comb(current, target):
    if sum(current) == target:
        yield current
    elif sum(current) < target:
        for coin in coins:
            for solution in comb(current + [coin], target):
                yield solution
```

However, this, too, seems to be too slow for getting all the combinations of coins.

Comment: Thanks. And, any ideas on how to implement a recursive function to solve this same problem? I'm terrible at recursion tbh..

Comment: Gah, generators + recursion really makes me go crazy D: Hopefully I'll understand this soon, but thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

[@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) indicates, you can use in this case `combinations_with_replacement` with `permutations` from `itertools`:

```
coins = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
perms = set() # invariant no repeated elements, 

# return elements with length=5 repeat
combinations = combinations_with_replacement(coins,5)

for comb in combinations:
    for c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 in permutations(comb):
        if sum([c1,c2,c3,c4,c5]) == 2:
            perms.add((c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))
```

**NOTE:** If you use a list in this case should be eliminated repeated or check in another way.