# A variable in a recursive function is acting non-local even though it should be local

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to generate a decision tree for a card game recursively, but a variable in one level of the recursion is somehow being treated as the same variable on another level of the recursion.

I've looked at how local and global variables work and I think they should all be local to that level. I've tried creating another variable that never interacts with other levels of the recursion, but it somehow is still treated as the same variable.

```
def generate_tree(hand, cards_left, play_to_beat, player_to_beat, player_no, self_no, hand_sizes):
    # Rest of function goes here
    # Recursive part
    children = []
    for move in moves:
        if not move:
            children.append(generate_tree(hand, cards_left, play_to_beat, player_to_beat, player_no + 1, self_no, hand_sizes))
        elif player_no == self_no:
            children.append(generate_tree(remove_items(hand, move), cards_left, move, player_no, player_no + 1, self_no, subtract_from_list_item(hand_sizes, player_no, 1)))                                        
        else:
            children.append(generate_tree(hand, remove_items(cards_left, move), move, player_no, player_no + 1, self_no, subtract_from_list_item(hand_sizes, player_no, 1)))        

    output = (hand_sizes, children)
    print(output)
    return output
```

`hand_sizes` and `cards_left` are the variables suffering from this, and I don't understand why this is happening to them and not `move` and `moves`. For example, hand_sizes is `[12, 13, 13, 1]`, and I give `[12, 13, 13, 0]` to the next level down's version of hand_sizes. This then changes all the hand_sizes for some reason; I can see in the debugger that all of them are changed. Does anybody know what is going on here?

Code for `subtract_from_list_item`:

```
def subtract_from_list_item(input_list, index, amount):
    output = input_list
    output[index] -= 1
    return output
```

Comment: So you are passing in a mutable list, mutate it, and pass it on without making a copy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python List values getting changed/mutated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604019/python-list-values-getting-changed-mutated)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `subtract_from_list_item` is a custom function which shouldn't mutate it, `remove_items` might but since `subtract_from_list_item` doesn't that can't be the problem.

Comment: [edit] your question. Code does not belong in comments. It looses its indentation.

Comment: @LIam Your code for ``subtract_from_list_item`` modifies the list. The aliasing ``output = input_list`` does not create a copy, and ``output[index] -= 1`` is an inplace modification.

Comment: But even in a comment, we can clearly see that the code *does* mutate the list, so I don't understand your assertion.

Comment: @Liam it might be useful to watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns has lots of info about why Python behaves the way it does in cases like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subtract_from_list_item` does modify the list. Assignment does not create a copy:

```
def subtract_from_list_item(input_list, index, amount):
    output = input_list  # `output` and `input_list` are the same list
    output[index] -= 1   # change the list known as `output` and `input_list`
    return output
```

The simplest fix is to create a copy before mutating the `list`:

```
def subtract_from_list_item(input_list, index, amount):
    output = input_list.copy()  # `output` and `input_list` are separate lists
    output[index] -= 1
    return output
```